# C# Razor: Why does this null check fail

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

Hi I am using C# razor with umbraco cms. I am trying to check if a variable is null or empty but it always returns an error. Here is the code

```
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.originalPageLink) == false)
{
   <div>Read the original page from <a href="@Model.originalPageLink">@Model.originalPageName</a></div>
}
```

When loading the page the razor script errors out. There is no particular error information that is useful. The part of the code thats giving me problems is this:

```
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.originalPageLink) == false)
```

I have tried this code here:

```
@if(Model.originalPageLink != null)
```

This code does not error out but returns a non null value when the string is really null.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: `@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.originalPageLink) )` should be fine. Can you post the error message that you get ?

Comment: I assume you actually have `IsNullOrEmpty(Model.originalPageLink)` and **not** `IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.originalPageLink)`, right?  The `@` in front of Model shouldn't be there -- you're already in the C# context at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK..I have figured it out.. Here is the solution

```
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.originalPageLink.ToString()) == false )
```

I have to put ToString() on the dynamic variable. Now it works correctly now.

Comment: Ah, you're using dynamic models.  You should consider strongly-typed models.  They are much more robust.  (Also, go ahead and **Accept** your answer.)

Comment: Umbraco CMS uses dynamic models exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

"when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"

Is it possible that Model is null? That is the only thing left that can possible be null...